# XCTAssertEqual failed: ("nan") is not equal to ("nan") in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, xctest

When I run the following test case, I get `XCTAssertEqual failed: ("nan") is not equal to ("nan")` error.

```swift
 XCTAssertEqual(0.0 / 0.0, Double.nan)
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: By reading the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/1641611-nan). NaN is never equal to any other value not even itself.

Comment: Quite clearly explained in the section on NaN here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/floatingpoint

Comment: What you need is to check if it [isNaN](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/floatingpoint/1641763-isnan)

Comment: I'll note that this isn't just a Swift thing, this is inherited from the IEEE 754 spec, which is arguably the most commonly used way to encode floating point numbers on machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Joakim said, `NaN` is never equal to any value, including itself.

You need to rewrite your code using [`isNaN`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/1539386-isnan):

```swift
let someValue = 0.0 / 0.0
XCTAssertFalse(someValue.isNaN) // Will detect that someValue is a NaN
```